# Get current value from h:input on ajax request

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I have this simple xhtml:

```
<h:inputText id="input-nome" value="#{bean.value}"  >
   <f:ajax listener="#{bean.myListener}"  event="keypress"  >
   </f:ajax>
</h:inputText>
```

and my listener:

```
public void myListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    UIInput input =  (UIInput) event.getSource();
    System.out.println(input.getValue());
System.out.println(getBean().getName());
}
```

I want get the current typed value, but in the listener I got always the previous value, for instance, if I type 'a' and 'b', the listener get only 'a' the previous value when I type 'ab'. If I type 'abc', I get 'ab'. How can I get the current input text value?

Comment: You already have `value="#{bean.value}"` there. Why not just doing `System.out.println(value)`..?

Answer (score 0):

Change event from `keypress` to `keyup`. You can add `execute="@this"` or `execute="input-nome"`.

> onkeyup : Client side callback to execute when a key is released over
>   input element.